# Trying to look for occurrences within a file after iterating through a directory. (Bash Script)

Tags: bash, file

I'm new to Bash Scripting and I wanted to make a script that would iterate through a directory searching for subdirectories and getting inside them to search for a specific string inside files that could be inside the previously mentioned subdirectories.

The problem I am currently having is actually with that second part. I am trying to access all the files one by one in the current subdirectory but it just doesn't work. It might be a stupid question but since I am new to this I find myself unable to find a solution to my problem. Here's the code:

```
if [[ $1 != "--help" ]]; 
then
    echo "counting results for string: "$1>results.txt
    let total=0

    for dir in */
    do
        if [[ -d $dir ]]; 
        then
            echo "directory: "$dir>>../results.txt
            let dirtotal=0
            cd $dir

            for i in */
            do
                if [[ -f $i ]]; 
                then
                    #look in the file i and count the number of occurrences
                    let result=`grep -c $1 $i`
                    echo $i": "$result
                    let dirtotal=$dirtotal+$result
                fi
            done

            echo "directory total: "$dirtotal>>../results.txt
            let total=$total+$dirtotal

            cd ..
        fi

    done

    echo "total: "$total>>results.txt

    exit 0

else
    display_error
    exit 1
fi
```

The problem occurs when making the second for...do...done loop.

Thanks.

Comment: `for i in */` will only match subdirectories, not files.

Comment: So how amd I supposed to search for files within that directory?

Comment: `for i in *` will match files and directories, then `if [[ -f "$i" ]]` will restrict to just files.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I had not good experiences here in SO back when I started programming in C and having to ask such a noobie question is usually embarrassing >.<

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for i in */
```

to:

```
for i in *
```

so that it matches files in addition to subdirectories.

Also, you should quote all your variables, in case they contain spaces or wildcard characters.

Answer (score 0):

you could use 'find' to look for files (-type f) and then search inside for the string. Note the double quotes around $1, using single quotes will not work.
xargs will execute the given command once for each filename piped on stdout. print0 separates matches with a null character, then xargs is instructed to read lines separated with null by the -0 option.

```
find /your/dir -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 grep "$1" | tee -a result.txt
```